# PostgreSQL - Default value for CURRENT_SETTING

Tags: postgresql

This is how I am accessing variable in PostgreSQL.

```
select CURRENT_SETTING('abc.var1')
```

Is there an optimal way so that I can get default value i.e. **0** in case variable doesn't exist, instead of receiving an error ?

Comment: Something like: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165361/assign-the-result-of-current-settingthe-setting-to-a-variable-in-pl-pgsql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the two parameter version of that function (which prevents an error if the variable is missing), then use coalesce():

```
select coalesce(current_setting('abc.var1', true), '0');
```